# Spring Boot | MyBatis project structure can't wire layers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis

Can't wire layers in **Spring Boot | MyBatis** application. The problem is probably happening when Service layer uses Mapper.

**Controller** method sample:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("demo")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "messages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMessages(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute(MESSAGE,  
                      messageService.selectMessages());
        return "messages";
}
```

**Service** class:

```
@Service
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired   // Not sure if I can use Autowired here.
    private MessageMapper messageMapper;

    public MessageService() {
    }

    public Collection<Message> selectMessages() { return 
         messageMapper.selectAll(); }

}
```

MyBatis **Mapper**:

```
@Mapper
public interface MessageMapper {
    @Select("select * from message")
    Collection<Message> selectAll();
}
```

**UPDATE**

It feels like I'm having some fundamental knowledge based mistake. Probably managing external libraries.

Here's maven `pom.xml`. Looks kind of overloaded, I faced a lot of errors managing different spring-boot packages. Starter for autoconfiguration included.
[pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/zdiyax/56eea63f9285771cd92f08a1f43309ab)

Here's the project structure:

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

I'm sure DB connection is working well, I'm able to track changes in MySQL Workbench while Spring Boot is executing `schema.sql` and `data.sql`. But somehow, MyBatis mapper methods throw **NullPointerException** and page proceeds with exit code 500. Seems like they can't connect.

Comment: Your are doing `new MessageService();` this creates an instance outside the control of Spring and no auto wiring will happen. You need to inject the `MessageService` into the controller as well.

Comment: @M. Deinum, I was thinking about that. However, when I try to inject it as `@Autowired private MessageService messageService` it gets underlined by IDEA and doesn't compile.

Comment: You also need to annotate your `MessageService` with `@Service` else it will not be detected. Also I doubt that it won't compile I suspect your IDE is telling you that `MessageService` cannot be auto wired.

Comment: Why doesn't it compile ? Post the error....

Comment: @M.Deinum, @PaulNUK, I updated how the code looks on this moment. It compiles, but still not working. You were right, IDEA argues the following: `Could not autowire: No beans of "MessageMapper" found.`

Comment: Have you properly configured MyBatis for Spring Boot (or included the starter so that you get autoconfiguration?). I'm assuming here that your spring boot application class is, as recommended, in a super package covering all packages with a component scan.

Comment: @M. Deinum, starter for autoconfiguration included. I updated answer again for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageService isn't managed by spring.

You have to annotate the MessageService class with @Service annotation (also, after adding this annotation you can indeed use @Autowired inside the service class)

```
@Service
public class MessageService {
  @Autowired  
  private MessageMapper messageMapper;

  public Collection<Message> selectMessages() { 
    return messageMapper.selectAll(); 
  }
}
```

and wire it to the controller with

```
@Autowired 
private MessageService messageService
```

and use it in a method like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "messages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMessages(ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute(MESSAGE,  messageService.selectMessages());
    return "messages";
}
```

Comment: When I annotate it like that, the declaration `@Autowired MessageMapper`  gets underlined by IDEA and doesn't compile.

Comment: remove the default constructor

Comment: strange, should be working. perhaps try removing the org.mybatis.mybatis.RELEASE dependency from pom (since you only need mybatis-spring-boot-starter)

Comment: well, MyBatis mapper is still not working. But that dependency was an excess. Thank you.